# SGX disabled by BIOS, kernel panic exitcode=0x00007f00

Tags: server

My machine is running Ubuntu 20.04 (Dual booted with windows 10). My Windows installation is working fine without any issues and I am able to operate on Windows but when I try to boot Ubuntu, it shows attached error
[image]
saying

```
SGX disabled by BIOS and Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
```

what might be the cause of this and how to fix it?

Comment: In some dual-boot situations you will need to *shut down* Windows, count to 10, then boot the machine and choose a non-Windows OS. When you choose "Restart" when switching between OSes, Windows can sometimes hold a lock on some devices (despite the restart) which blocks other OSes from gaining access to the hardware 

Comment: @matigo thanks for your comment, I will give it a try this way and see if it helps:)

Comment: @matigo I'm sorry to update that it didn't make any differences. I also tried to use a new Ubuntu OS trying to copy my data from that crashed system, but I can't access my /home or /tmp folders, it prompted that structure needs cleaning. Any idea?

Comment: try explaining what sgx is but from what i understand from the answer above that is provided is the bios is locked from non windows operating systems from accessing certain proprietary bios options , am i wrong please elaberate on this topic more id like to hear more of this